# Code of demo.sonata-project.org

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

Is it possible to have the code of [this sonata app](http://demo.sonata-project.org) ?

Answer (score 3):

The code can be found [here](https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox) it is a bit outdated but there is an activity lately https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox/pull/608

Answer (score 0):

You should read, install and configure all bundle that you need from sonata documentation: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/3-x/doc/index.html

Official sonata github repo: https://github.com/sonata-project